# Ray can't detect sensor objects?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

My ray cannot detect a sensor object. I can't make the object anything other than a sensor. How can I have a ray detect sensor objects?

Comment: That the definition of a sensor. It can sense, but ultimately can't *be* sensed. the ultimate physics type for stealth planes. In order for it to be sensed, you need to change it to maybe static, but you can turn ghost on.

Comment: Radish of the Opera is right. I'm not sure if this is what you want to do, but in order to detect object with sensor brick, you could just give them adequate property and seek for the objects with this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensors are not detectable via ray detection.

Typically sensors sense other objects rather then being detected.

**Workaround:**
Add another object that fills the sensor object. Give it a physics type that can be sensed via ray. Parent it to the sensor (or the other way around). Ensure your sensor ignores this object. This way the ray can detect the new object.